# How to ping IDN domain hosts in bash script?

Tags: dns, ping

I have the following bash script file.

```
ping -с 1 $(idn2 президент.рф)                                                  

ping -с 1 $(idn2 правительство.рф)                                              

ping -с 1 $(idn2 яндекс.рф)
```

When I run it, I get an error: `ping: invalid option -- '�'`

But when I type these commands by hand in my terminal it runs fine.

Is there a way to run these commands from file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not careful to type 'c' letter in `-c` option as non-ASCII letter. That was the problem. I fixed it and the problem has gone.

Make sure you type bash commands and their options in ASCII.